# Can't open hdri in Blender 2.8 release candidate

Tags: world, hdri

do you also have issue with opening HDRI in Blender 2.8 release candidate? Did something changed?
My approach is to go to the world settings, change color to an environment texture, click to open texture, but all HDRIs are invisible for Blender. I tried switch off filters or move HDRI directly to the world window, but nothing happens. I checked also addons, did I miss something?

Comment: Works for me. What exactly do you mean by invisible? Does the file browser not display them or is it missing in the render?

Comment: File browser doesn't display them. I tried previous version of Blender 2.8 and I have same problem. But it worked before.

Comment: it's not visible if you're in Orthographic view mode, is it your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird, but when I copied HDRI to different folder then it works. Even HDRIs in previous folder are visible.

Comment: Could have something to do with permissions to access the directory.

Comment: Sounds logical. I installed new version of Blender today, so it's possible it needed some permission.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably accidentally removed image files from the filtering in the file browser. Make sure that when filtering is turned on that the image icon is also enabled. Otherwise it won't display image files.

[image]

Comment: I see PNGs and I tried turn on and off all filters. HDRI doesn't show.

Comment: That's weird. What file extensions do they have? Could it be that they are marked as hidden files?